# Embedded image in SVG not showing in Opera and Firefox when file extension is "jpeg"

Tags: html, svg

I've been playing around with svg-creation the last couple of days and came across a weird problem with embedded jpg-images.

I've been developing and testing in Chrome where everything was fine. But when I opened up the test site in Firefox 25.0 and Opera 12.16 some jpg-Images I embedded in the SVG weren't showing up.

It turns out, the ones that are not showing have the file-extension "jpeg". The ones with the extension jpg are showing correctly. What's more, when I have them in the browser cache, they are shown.
I made an example in JSBin

http://jsbin.com/aSILObi/1/

Both images exist, but only the one ending in jpg is shown in the svg.

Has anyone an idea what might be the problem here?

Comment: The one ending in jpeg returns a 404 in your example.

Comment: Not for me. The url displays the image: http://api.discogs.com/image/A-689488-1188105337.jpeg
**EDIT:** Strange thing here: In Firebug there is a 404, but when i hover the error in the Firebug-Console the image is shown.

Comment: weird. curl -I http://api.discogs.com/image/A-689488-1188105337.jpeg HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: I'm seeing two images, how many are there supposed to be?

Comment: There are supposed to be two images. It really is a strange behaviour. I tested it on different machines and on every machine in chrome it works fine whereas firefox only displays the on ending in "jpg". But if the one ending in "jpeg" is in the firefox-cache e.g. by openeing the image directly in the browser it is displayed.